# Samsung gear 2 heart rate

Tags: android, android-sensors, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

Can anyone please help me with getting heart rate data from gear 2 in an android app.

Can I get this via android wear sensor manager like gear live or have to use accessory sdk of samsung.

Comment: Do you all read questions before marking as duplicate...samsung gear 2 is no longer working on android OS , hence you cannot use android wear sensor programming to query heart rate like gear live as far as i know, just wanted a bit more clarity on that , as it must be queried using tizen sdk....

Comment: Can anyone who is having knowledge explain a bit more to me would be very helpful, request you all to not mark questions as duplicate without knowing answers